# DXF/DWG not loading into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, pdf, dxf

So I was following the directions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/169914/17847 and extracted a DXF/DWG from a PDF. When I try to load the DXF/DWG into ArcGIS Pro. However, I do not see anything:

[image]

I should be seeing at least a part of a polygon there but I'm not.

Here's the PDF:

https://www.terrafrost.com/community_registry_map_7.pdf

Here's the DXF/DWG that I extracted:

https://www.terrafrost.com/community_registry_map_7.dxf

Any ideas?

Comment: It probably doesn't have georeference information or, if it does, it's not defined and different to your canvas. The layer properties should show you the extent of the DXF and the coordinate reference system, check these and fix as necessary (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/georeferencing-vector-layer-with-control-points-using-qgis might help).

Comment: @MichaelStimson - `gdalinfo` would seem to imply that the PDF is georeferenced. I'll check out your link. Thanks

Comment: The issue may not be related to whether the PDF is georeferenced or not, but whether the resulting DXF is gereferenced.  What does `gdalinfo` say about the DXF?  What does ArcGIS say about the coordinate system of the layer when you load it up in ArcGIS?  (I can't check because your links are blocked by our company security.)